# Глобальная переменная в getScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, переменные

Здравствуйте, не могу изменить переменную...

```
function test() {
    var val = false;
    $.getScript('/api.js', function() {
        val = true;
    })

    return val; 
}
```

Что здесь не так?

Comment: Ваш код асинхронен, сэр.

Comment: А как сделать глобальную переменную!?

Comment: а зачем вам глобальная переменная ? просто не выходите за рамки своего scope.

Comment: Мне нужно в ретурн запихивать результат подключаемой функции. Что бы потом проверять ее в другом скрипте.

Comment: это невозможно, код асинхронный. это главное что вам нужно понять для продолжения совершенствования своего js-fu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно загрузить код синхронно, но советую всё же понять JavaScript и его идеологию:

```
// Так делать неправильно
function test() {
    var val = false;
    $.ajax('/api.js', { dataType: 'script', async: false }, function() {
        val = true;
    })
    return val; 
}

// true way
$.getScript('/api.js').done(function (){
    // script loaded
    test(); // call user function
});
```

Comment: @Чад более идеологично пример написал.

Answer (score 2):

Можно как то так попробовать, через функцию.

```
function test(callback) {
    var val = false;
    $.getScript('/api.js', function() {
        val = true;
        callback(val);
    })

}

test(function(result){console.log(result);});
```

Глобальную переменную просто:

```
  var globals = {};
  ...
  function test() {
      globals.val = false;
  ...
  }
```

Comment: Нужно что либо попроще...